# How to access tailwind.Config.js properties in app.js

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, vite

I want to access tailwind.Config.js properties in app.js. I followed this official article https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script
but it gives me the following error:

```
Could not resolve "./tailwind.config.js" from "resources/js/app.js"
file: /localhost/public_html/resources/js/app.js
error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve "./tailwind.config.js" from "resources/js/app.js"
    at error (file:///localhost/public_html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2245:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///localhost/public_html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24674:24)
    at file:///localhost/public_html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24636:26
```

I'm Using laravel 10 with vite

this is the code that causes the error in app.js

```
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig';
import tailwindConfig from './tailwind.config.js';

const fullConfig  = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Vite with Laravel, importing a non-JavaScript or non-JSON file directly into your JavaScript can cause issues because Vite does not handle it the same way Webpack does. To handle this issue:

- Method 1.

create a tailwind-config.js:

```
import tailwindConfig from './tailwind.config.js';
export default JSON.stringify(tailwindConfig);
```

Then in your app.js, you can import:

```
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig';
import tailwindConfig from './tailwind-config';

const fullConfig = resolveConfig(JSON.parse(tailwindConfig));
```

- Method 2.

you can define a global constant in your vite.config.js:

```
import tailwindConfig from './tailwind.config.js';

export default defineConfig({
  //other codes
  define: {
    'process.env.TAILWIND_CONFIG': JSON.stringify(tailwindConfig),
  },
});
```

in your app.js, you can access it:

```
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig';

const fullConfig = resolveConfig(JSON.parse(process.env.TAILWIND_CONFIG));
```